# how to put image variable between image helper quotes 

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

app\views\images/view.ctp
this is the views code ..i need help to fetch image

```
            <?php
            // initialise a counter for striping the table
            $count = 0;

            // loop through and display format
            foreach($images as $image){
                // stripes the table by adding a class to every other row
                $class = ( ($count % 2) ? " class='altrow'": '' );
                // increment count
                $count++;



  $full3 = '/img/images/'.$image['Image'];
  $thumb3 = $this->Html->image('images/image-1.jpg',array("width"=>"60", "height"=>"40"));
  var_dump($full3) ;

      $this->Html->link($thumb3,$full3,array('escape' => false, 'rel' => 'lightbox[plants]','title'=>'thanks allah for help me'));
         }
          ?>
```

the controller code is images_controller code..

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid image', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('image', $this->Image->read(null, $id));
 $images=  $this->Image->find('all');
   $this->set('images', $images);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this line

```
echo $thumb3 = $this->Html->image('images"/".$image['Image']['img_file']',array('width'=>"60", 'height'=>"40"));
```

with

```
echo $thumb3 = $this->Html->image("images/".$image['Image']['img_file'],array("width"=>"60", "height"=>"40"));
```

Comment: i still cant see the image...i think it must like this format to see the photo  'images/image-1.jpg' ..you put the quoutes after photo ..

Comment: i have already updated my post. there is no need to put quotes in the end

Comment: also use var_dump($thumb3) to see what url is being created

Comment: it is give me this value  string(71) "

Comment: when var_dump($thumb3) gives you output like string(71) then after it there is a string also tell me what is that string.

Comment: $full3 = '/img/images/'.$image['Image']['img_file'];
  $thumb3 = $this->Html->image('images/image-1.jpg',array("width"=>"60", "height"=>"40"));

     echo $this->Html->link($thumb3,$full3,array('escape' => false, 'rel' => 'lightbox[plants]','title'=>'this is title'));

Comment: can you give me the exact output of var_dump($thumb3)? string(71) is the only half of output, there is more output as well

Comment: where are the images, its in "/img/images" or "/images" ?

Comment: when i use Html->image helper i just use /images , but when i dont use this helper i put this code /img/images/

Comment: ok now compare the output of var_dump($full3) and var_dump($thumb3), it will tell you where is the problem in image path.

Comment: this is the full root  webroot/img/images/image-jpg

Comment: i tested your code, it works fine for me. the only thing which can make problem for you is $image['Image']['img_file']...check it with var_dump($image['Image']['img_file']) and see what file name is displayed

Comment: yeah i tested your code on my localhost it is working correctly. run this code var_dump($image['Image']['img_file']); give me its output, and make sure this file exists.

Comment: i want to explain something ,i use loop to see images from database so when i put var_dump($full3) ;  , i see all images and its id like this ....string(12) "DSC01242.JPG" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(12) "DSC00061.JPG" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(12) "DSC01240.JPG" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(12) "DSC01224.JPG" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(12) "DSC01208.jpg" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(12) "DSC01248.JPG" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(19) "cover_moslym_02.jpg" string(17) "/img/images/Array" string(16)

Comment: this is the problem "/img/images/Array". you have problem with your for loop, its printing something wrong.

Comment: are you look in the above first question..i put all code..please look at the code

Comment: Kashif Khan i corrected $full3,, it is now and it is work good $full3 = '/img/images/'.$image['Image']['img_file'];

Comment: replace this line $full3 = '/img/images/'.$image['Image']; with $full3 = '/img/images/'.$image['Image']['img_file']; i guess img_file column contains the file name

Comment: the problem with   $thumb3 = $this->Html->image('images/image-1.jpg',array("width"=>"60", "height"=>"40"));

Comment: when i use this link  $thumb3 = $this->Html->image("images/".$image['Image']['img_file'],array("width"=>"60", "height"=>"40"));
and use this var_dump($thumb3); ... i see string(72) "" string(72) "" string(72) "" string(72) "" string(72) "" string(72) "" string(79) "" string(76) "" string(81) ""

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6106/discussion-between-user1080247-and-kashif-khan)